# dealing with large number of pictures

Tags: windows, image, video, store

My program save images from a camera in a rate about 30fps;
Moving these images or browsing them by windows explorer take a long time.

My questions is:
is storing them as a video file is a better approach? so moving files wouldn't take a lot of time. (if this is good, how to open a large video file and get a specified frame number fast? Is this approach faster?)

Comment: What are these images, JPEG?  What kind of computing environment are you in (Linux, Windows, Mac, etc?) What are you doing with these images -- what kind of access to them is required?

Comment: jpegs, Windows, C++, It's not the matter of processing, I do my process int real time as I get the picture from camera, the question is about storing them, I need just a specified frame with some meta data that I have saved them in file name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very unlikely that a video file will load or seek any faster than individual image files. Not to mention this is going to be a lot more difficult to handle than images, and probably introduce a bunch of extra, unnecessary dependencies to your application.

**If you really need a way to speed up image browsing, you should look into generating separate [*thumbnail* images](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thumbnail).** Thumbnails are exact duplicates of the original images, but with significant reductions in size and quality, suitable for display purposes only. This makes the resulting thumbnail images *significantly* smaller than the originals, which should speed up their loading and rendering substantially. This trick is used all over graphics packages and file managers. This approach allows you to delay the expensive process of loading the associated full image until after the user selects a particular thumbnail image to open.